# WebKit.Net and OpenWebKitSharp Error: Failed to initialize activation context

Tags: c#, exception, webkit, webkit.net, activation-context-api

I am using both/either WebKit.Net and OpenWebKitSharp.  However, as soon as I try to instantiate the WebKitBrowser, I get an error: Failed to initialize activation context
Does anybody know what this is?

Answer (score 23):

This error would ocur occur only in case OpenWebKitSharp.manifest and other WebKit files are missing from your exe's folder. Try copying every file from the "Core" folder to your debug/release directory.

Answer (score 11):

Just Copy All files inside (WebKit.NET-0.5-bin-cairo\bin)